# ODOO Communication between widgets

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

How can I communicate between multiple widgets?
I have 2 widgets on the same page, and when clicking on one of the first widget button, I need to modify the content of the second widget.

Can anyone help me?

Details:
I extend FieldMany2One (selectbox) and ListView. What I need is, when select an option in FieldMany2One, I need to update content in ListView. What I need is to get an instantiated widget into another widget.
In method reinit_value of FieldMany2One widget, I need to get instance of the ListView.

Best regards,
Pedro

Comment: which kind of widget are they? could you post part of your view code?

Comment: Hi @AlessandroRuffolo ty, I edit my question in section "Details:". Can you see please?

Comment: mh, this is client side code. Sorry but I do not know how to help you :(

Comment: Hi @AlessandroRuffolo ty anyway ;)